# Objective-C : UIScrollView manual paging

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiscrollview, paging

I want to use the scrollview as something like a picker in horizontal mode.
The scrollview holds up to seven subviews.
Each subview represents a value.
Always three views are visible and the one in the middle is the selected one.

Scrollview visible at start:

__ | V1 | V2

Scrollview set to view/value two:

V1 | V2 | V3

Scrollview set to last value:

V2 | V3 | __

The real problem I have got is the "pagingEnabled" flag.
If pagingEnabled is set to YES the scrollview pages always three subviews/values instead of only one.
If pagingEnabled is set to NO the scrollview does not clinch.

Is there a nice solution for my problem?

Thanks a lot,
Dan ;)

Comment: See my answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10993426/60488

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the frame of the scrollview to be as if it were only displaying the middle view (i.e. a third of its original width, and offset by the same amount), but then set its `clipsToBounds` property to NO.

Comment: This is a nice solution. Thanks :D

Comment: But wouldn't you still wish to show the user part of V1 and V3 while they are selecting V2?  Didn't shrinking the width to 1/3 make it so that only 1 item was visible at a time?  (I would think you would want 1/2 + 1 + 1/2 visible at once.  No?

Comment: Read the OP's post -- he wants 1 + 1 + 1 visible at once, not 1/2 + 1 + 1/2. And take a look at the documentation to see what setting `clipsToBounds` to NO achieves :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution if anyone else is interested.

Assign you view the delegate of a scrollview. Ovveride scrollViewDidEndDecelerating, afterwards get your current index(page you want) by doing something like.

```
 NSNumber* currentIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:round(scrollview.Contentoffset.x / PAGE_SIZE)];

//Then just update your scrollviews offset with


[scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake([currentIndex intValue] * PAGE_SIZE, 0) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 5, there's the [`scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewWillEndDragging%3awithVelocity%3atargetContentOffset%3a) delegate method on `UIScrollViewDelegate`. This allows you to implement arbitrary paging.

For this to work, you first need to set the `pagingEnabled` property to `NO`, otherwise the delegate method I'm talking about isn't called. The scroll view now calls this delegate method whenever the user lifts his finger and the scroll view wants to determine where to finish the scrolling.

The magic is the last argument, `targetContentOffset`: it's a pointer to a `CGPoint` and used as a in/out variable. This means this variable tells you where the scrollview wants to scroll to. But it allows you modify this target location. The `velocity` might also be of interest, it can give you an indication whether the user "pushed" the scroll view or moved it, stopped, then lifted his finger.

For example, here's an implementation that rounds the target `x` location to the nearest multiple of 100, thus making "pages" of 100 points width.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    targetContentOffset->x = round(targetContentOffset->x / 100.0) * 100.0;
}
```